# SQL Join or Union?

Tags: sql, join, union

I have two tables:

```
Customer    Time    Program
-----------------------------------
1           8:05    a
2           9:38    b
3           10:45   c
4           12:00   a

Customer    Time    Program
-----------------------------------
1           11:30   d
5           1:45    e
6           9:45    f
7           2:15    g
```

I want my table to look like:

```
Customer    Time    Program
-----------------------------------
1           8:05    a
1           11:30   d
2           9:38    b
3           10:45   c
4           12:00   a
5           1:45    e
6           9:45    f
7           2:15    g
```

It's really simple, but my time columns have different names in each of the tables and each table has a different set of programs so no program id will be in both tables.

Comment: That's a `UNION`. Doesn't matter if the `time` columns have different names.

Comment: This is pretty straight forward. What have you tried?

Comment: I knew it would be pretty straight forward, and I tried both. This database is just so big and complicated that I can't tell which one is working correctly so I wanted to double check! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want a UNION. UNION concatenates the rows of two tables, preserving the columns; JOIN associates columns of two different tables into rows.

You can rename columns in the SELECTs that make the union:

```
SELECT Customer, FirstTime AS Time, Program FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT Customer, SecondTime AS Time, Program FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 2):

UNION them and use AS to call the columns by names that match between the two tables

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`:

[Problems uploading code]

```
select customer, time, program from table1
union all

select customer, time, program from table2
```

`union` adds extra processing to remove duplicates.